# Deployment failed with HRESULT:0x80073CF9/Deployment Add operation failed with error 0x80070002

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

I am trying to deploy my Windows Universal test App built in Visual Studio 2015 RC on a recently upgraded HP Windows 10 tablet.

But app fails to install. The same application is correctly installed on my Windows 10 Laptop.

Complete error :

> "Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT:0x80073CF9, Install
>   failed. Please contact your software vendor.
>
> Deployment Add operation with target volume C: on Package
>   2ccd2f92-3e7f-4781-94d4-77de6896ad81_2015.810.607.4634_neutral_~_432wcw9hw150w from:() failed with error 0x80070002. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
>   deployment issues.
>
> NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId]
>   45afcb8b-d363-0002-58da-af4563d001 in the Event Log or use the command
>   line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 45afcb8b-d363-0002-58da-af4563d001
>
> At C:\myapp\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1:388 char:13
>   +             Add-AppxPackage -Path $DeveloperPackagePath.FullName -ForceApplicati ...
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\myapp\p....1.0.3_ARM.appbundle:String) [Add-AppxPackage],
>   IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
>
> Error: Could not install the package."

Tried the fix from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/910336.
 Also checked the reference links in error but no helpful diagnosis for this error code is given.

Earlier I was able to install test apps on Windows 8.1 version using same process. Can it be due to Windows 10 upgrade? Any ideas?

Comment: Would recommend to upgrade to VS2015 final. Get it from http://visualstudio.com. It might fix your problem. If not, you're at least on the most current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem occurs only when System login is through Microsoft Account.

I removed the MS account and used the local Device Account. It fixed the problem.

Still not aware of the exact root cause. Must be something to do with Account permissions. (Although MS account I used had Admin privileges.)

Answer (score 0):

I was met with the same problem with same error code. But in my case, in the phone earlier the project with the same App name was present, and I was trying to deploy the App of next version with a change in App certificate.
So, uninstalling the previous App from phone, and re-installing the App with certificate worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some interesting hint direct from Microsoft Forum: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/help-with-0x80073cf9-on-windows-10/a1bd57d1-4bfe-4f9d-91c2-0a87c596f983

Answer (score -1):

```
Add-AppxPackage: Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF9, Install failed. 
Please contact your software vendor. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF9)
```

For rectifying this you only need to run PowerShell as admin